# Classic ASP: Page Reference

Tags: asp-classic, include, href

I have three pages in Classic ASP:

```
Root>Login>login.asp
Root>Web>index.asp
Root>Web>Section>index.asp
```

In Root>Web>index.asp and Root>Web>Section>index.asp I include Root>Login>login.asp:

```
Root>Web>index.asp: <!--#include file="../login/login.asp" -->
Root>Web>Section>index.asp: <!--#include file="../../login/login.asp" -->
```

But my problem is:

on Login.asp I do a redirect to Root>index.asp if the session is expired.

```
RESPONSE.REDIRECT("../index.asp")
```

works for `Root>Web>index.asp` but - of course - doesn't works for  `Root>Web>Section>index.asp` because of the "href referencial"

In HTML I do this:

```
<base href="../../">
```

Are there any similar solution on ASP or I need to make an IF for each one?

Answer (score 2):

In ASP :

"/" > redirect to the root then the best solution for this problem is simply, put / without ..

```
RESPONSE.REDIRECT("/index.asp")
```

Comment: Also, instead of `#include file="../../login/index.asp" ` you could use `<!--#include virtual="/login/login.asp" -->`